# ActionResult on a Partial View changes the main view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've got a page that opens a kendo ui Window to show data contained in a partial view... I've a button inside this partial view that performs a save on DB...when the Action is completed I got the main page to be redirect to the View I've in the modal... how can I fix this? shouldn't that view/controller only live in the popup I opened?

Condider this Main Page shows a list of users with a grid.
I click on a button an I open this

```
var mywindow = $("#window");

        mywindow.kendoWindow({
            width: "615px",
            title: "Cambio Password",
            content: "CambioPassword",
            modal : true
        });
        mywindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
```

My CambioPasswordController  is

```
[Authorize]
public class CambioPasswordController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IAdminRepository adminRepository;

    public CambioPasswordController(IAdminRepository adminRepository)
    {
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CambioPasswordModel cambioPasswordModel = new CambioPasswordModel();

        if (this.Request.Params.Count > 0 && (this.Request.Params)["IdUser"] != null)
            cambioPasswordModel.IdUser = Convert.ToInt32((this.Request.Params)["IdUser"]);

        return PartialView(cambioPasswordModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CambioPassword(CambioPasswordModel newPwd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = SessionHelper.GetObjectFromSession<Utente>(this.Session, "user");

            var result = adminRepository.CambioPassword(newPwd.IdUser.ToString(), newPwd.Password, user.IDInterno);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Message))
            {
                TempData["message"] = result.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["message"] = "Password cambiata con successo";
                //chiudi la finestra
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Errore cambio password");
        }
        return PartialView("Index"); // <<<------ THIS LEADS THE MAIN PAGE TO go to /CambioPassword/Index
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
    }